# Applications using Schur complements

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, block-matrices, schur-complement

I wonder if you may be able to contribute some areas/ideas where Schur complements are used. For example, I think Schur complements can be used to check for positive definiteness of a matrix.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Schur complements are often used in the context of convex optimization. As an example, consider the following problem
$$
\begin{aligned}
\min \quad & f(x) \\
\textrm{s.t.} \quad & x^TAx \leq t
\end{aligned} \tag{1}
$$
where $f : X \to \mathbb R$ is a convex function, where $X \subset \mathbb R^n$, $A$ is a positive-definite matrix, and $t > 0$. The constraint $x^TAx \leq t$ is quadratic in $x$, which can be difficult to work with in practice. Instead, because $A$ is positive-definite, then
$$
\begin{align}
x^TAx \leq t &\iff t - x^TAx \geq 0 \\
&\iff \begin{bmatrix}A^{-1} & x \\ x^T & t\end{bmatrix} \succeq 0 \tag{2} \\
\end{align}
$$
where we used the Schur complement lemma to obtain $(2)$. Note that the left-hand side of the inequality in $(2)$ is linear in $x$ rather than quadratic. Therefore, the problem in $(1)$ becomes
$$
\begin{aligned}
\min \quad & f(x) \\
\textrm{s.t.} \quad & \begin{bmatrix}A^{-1} & x \\ x^T & t\end{bmatrix} \succeq 0
\end{aligned}
$$
This substitution, for example, comes up in the case of [quadratically constrained quadratic programs](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratically_constrained_quadratic_program).